# Sql server database consolidation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say there are 500 lan connected machines all running sql express and dumping some data on on their own local db. 
I want a central machine to periodically read the updated data from all individual machine and update the central database. 
I can develop and host a console app on central machine that opens connection to individual machine and fetch the latest data to update on central machine. The schemas of each local database is the same. 
I don't want to backup and save because i want to run reporting on the central db and tabular data will be much more simpler. 
Are there other ways I can approach this problem. Mine sounds boring.

Comment: We don't really do software design at SO, because it's subjective/opinion based and it's this hard to say "this is the correct answer/accept" - other answers could be equally correct and the opinion requirement can lead to disagreement

Comment: If I was approaching this task I'd get a list of all the connection strings and tables, I'd programmatically create an UpdatedDate column in each table and programmatically create a trigger to update it whenever an UPDATE occurs, and the central program would have a db if it's own that it pulled the data into based on the updateddate column. The central program would track each db, connection string and last time the updates were polled. It should get the time from the remote server though, not the local

Comment: Have a look at [Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may sound boring but practically it will work.

Your central DB can have a dedicated table that contains connection settings to your multiple local DB and then you can use these settings to connect with your local DB and make transactions for getting data for reporting purposes.

So your DBs may look like below:

- Central_DB (DB for reporting purposes and also contains connection
  settings to local DBs)
- Client_1_DB
- Client_2_DB
- Client_N_DB

If you really have that workloads on local DB then its good to maintain a separate server / physical system. But if you don't have that much of loads i would recommend using one physical system with enough hardware and in that you can define a DB for settings and separate DB for each clients / employee / whatever, this will save you cost on licensing OS and SQL Server.

The system i am working on is using almost similar approach but its kind of robust, because the DB is hosted on cloud. We have a master DB that contains settings to seperate client DBs and we use the connection settings from master DB to create context on server side for making transactions.

Side note : You may also want to consider the possibilities of a local DB going down (since it is a physical system) and backing it up daily/weekly/period you want to set.

Good luck!